# Express OAuth Github

Tags: javascript, express, github

```
  githubCallback = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const user = req.user as User;

    const refreshToken = getRefreshToken();
    await this.saveRefreshToken(refreshToken, user.id);

    res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: oneWeek,
    });

    res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/`);
  };
```

This is my callback function, after I successfully logged with github.

I use JWT token, and have AccessToken, and RefreshToken.

On client I store AccessToken in localstorage, this token live only 10 minutes, so It's pretty safe.

My RefreshToken stored in cookies with httpOnly flag, and it live longer, in my case 1 week.

After sign in/sign up with email I set it to cookies like in the code, but I return accessToken in JSON. So on client I can easily get it, and put to localStorage.

So, my question is, hot to throw accessToken to client after github auth, the most simple way is to put to url, but it not safe, what else can I do with it?